# WebSocket connection on iPhone is dropped when phone goes to standby mode

Tags: iphone, safari, websocket, socket.io

I have a web application that creates a WebSocket connection to a server on page ready. However once the phone goes to sleep/standby and then I wake it up, the application appears to have lost that connection. Is this expected? How do I code around this in my webpage in Safari so that I can detect the connection loss and detect when the phone comes out of standby so that I can re-connect? I am using node.js on the back end with the socket.io library on the server and the client.

Thanks!

Comment: When the phone comes out of standby is your websocket's onerror or onclose callback run?

Comment: simonc - thanks for your comment. That helps. I am now detecting a dropped connection and will display a reconnect prompt when coming out of standby.